# Why did Ramsay believe in the given proofs?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S06E03 (*Oathbreaker*)

> Smalljon Umber shows a boy and mentions that it is Rickon Stark. At first, Ramsay doesn't believe it. But after Umber displays a Direwolf's head, he suddenly changes his mind and says "welcome home, lord Stark". But in Westeros there exist other direwolfs.

So, why did Ramsay believe him?

Comment: `... in Westeros there exist other [spoilers]` <-- Which all belonged to House Stark.

Comment: @Mooz nope, in the first book in chapters "Jon I" and "Tyrion III" it was mentioned that some people seen and heard them

Comment: @shullz [Not south of The Wall](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Direwolf#Quotes)

Answer (score 22):

You are incorrect in thinking that there are other Direwolves in Westeros. In fact, the only ones south of the Wall belong to House Stark, specifically:

- [Grey Wind](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Grey_Wind)<sup>[deceased]</sup>: belonging to Robb
- [Lady](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Lady)<sup>[deceased]</sup>: belonging to Sansa
- [Summer](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Summer): belonging to Bran
- [Nymeria](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Nymeria_(direwolf)): belonging to Arya
- [Shaggydog](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Shaggydog)<sup>[deceased]</sup>: belonging to Rickon
- [Ghost](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost): belonging to Jon Snow

> By the reign of King Robert Baratheon no direwolf had been sighted south of the Wall, even in the Stark lands of the North, in over 200 years.<sup>[[1]](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Direwolves#The_Stark_direwolves)</sup>

Anyone who sees a Direwolf will immediately know that it belongs to one of the Stark kids.

In fact, all throughout the books there is mention of using a Direwolf to prove that the kids are Starks, especially Rickon (who is by the way in a different situation).

Comment: But Jeor Mormont  and Benjen Stark mentioned that recently appeared some direwolves (because winter became closer). Their opinions should be more reliable than opinion of  Teon

Comment: Anyone who sees not just a direwolf, but direwolf and man together will immediately know that it belongs to one of the Stark kids

Comment: @Schullz - IIRC those direwolf sightings were all north of the Wall. South of the wall they remain so damned rare that any you see will almost certainly be one of the Stark direwolves.

Comment: I also remember reading about sightings of _A_ direwolf in the north, south of the wall. I always took this as an appearance of Nymeria. I strongly believe it is Nymeria. These sightings only occur after she and Arya depart ways.

Comment: @user1129682 Yes, this was in the Riverlands. There are mentions of a sightings of a "she wolf" who is said to be large and is the leader of a large wolf pack in that region. And yes, it is a nod to Nymeria.

Answer (score 2):

Direwolves are not at all common south of the Wall, the show touches on this:

> ROBB: There are no direwolves south of the Wall.
>   
> JON: **Now there are five**.
>   
> <sub>Game of Thrones, S01 E01, "Winter is Coming"</sub>

And we do get some more information from the books:

> "It's no freak," Jon said calmly. "That's a direwolf. They grow larger than the other kind."
>   
> Theon Greyjoy said, "**There's not been a direwolf sighted south of the Wall in two hundred years**."
>   
> "I see one now," Jon replied.
>   
> <sub>A Game of Thrones, Bran I</sub>

So it appears that the only known ones south of the Wall are the ones held by the Stark family. This is then a very easy way to recognise a Stark. Now let's find out about the whereabouts of each of them:

- Robb/Grey Wind: Killed by Frey soldiers in S03 E09 "The Rains of Castamere"
- Jon/Ghost: Alive and with Jon
- Sansa/Lady: Killed by Ned Stark after Robert made the order on Cersei's request in S01 E02 "The Kingsroad"
- Arya/Nymeria: Whereabouts unknown, last seen running away when Arya sends her off in S01 E02 "The Kingsroad"
- Bran/Summer: Last seen going north of the Wall with Bran, however, he is killed in Season 6 Episode 5, "The Door", fending off the wight party.
- Rickon/Shaggydog: Last seen with Rickon when Bran sends him away in S03 E09 "The Rains of Castamere"

So from the list the only known direwolves still around are Ghost, Nymeria and Shaggydog. Ghost is too dissimilar from the rest of the wolves for it to have been him and Nymeria is known to have been set loose so the most likely option is that the head is of Shaggydog.

---

Note, as of Season 7 Episode 2, "Stormborn", we also know that Nymeria is still alive and well when she reunites with Arya:

This leaves the only option for the head to have been Shaggydog's, though of course this is not known to Ramsay at the time.